# How can I make an <svg> element scale to a parent element's height?

Tags: html, css, svg

I have an `<svg>` element within a wrapping element.

I want the `<svg>` to fill the height of the wrapping element, however I cannot seem to get this to work.

I have tried the following:

```css
.image-banner__overlay {
  height: 90%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 999;
}

svg {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: black;
}

path {
  fill: red;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="cell small-12 medium-6 image-banner__image-wrapper">
  <div class="image-banner__overlay">
    <svg>
                <path d="M91.91,125c0-50.63,10.58-95.75,27.07-125H69.22V250H119C102.49,220.75,91.91,175.63,91.91,125Z" transform="translate(-69.22)" />
            </svg>
  </div>
  <div class="image-banner__image" style="@backgroundImage">
  </div>
</div>
```

But the `<svg>` seems to only ever take up a max of about 75% of the space, eg:

[image: SVG in red]

I've tried using viewBox, eg:

`height="100%" width="100%" viewBox="0 0 100 100"  preserveAspectRatio="none"`

But this makes the SVG way too big (overflows the parent element).

Would anyone know how I could get this to stretch the complete height of the parent element (without turning it into an `<img>`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a viewbox for you, I know it's horrible but you should [read up on it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/viewBox)!

```css
.image-banner__overlay {
  height: 90%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 999;
}

svg {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: black;
}

path {
  fill: red;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="cell small-12 medium-6 image-banner__image-wrapper">
  <div class="image-banner__overlay">
    <svg viewbox="0 0 80 250">
            <path d="M91.91,125c0-50.63,10.58-95.75,27.07-125H69.22V250H119C102.49,220.75,91.91,175.63,91.91,125Z" transform="translate(-69.22)" />
        </svg>
  </div>
  <div class="image-banner__image" style="@backgroundImage">
  </div>
</div>
```